# How to refactor function with observable

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I refactor this part of code? I want to reduce the amount of 'else if' statements. I tried to use || operator, but it's doesn't work.

```
getNominieesByStage(stage_key: string): Observable<any> {

    const simpleObservable$ = new Observable<any>((observer) => {

      if (stage_key === 'key1') {
        observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      } else if (stage_key === 'key2') {
        observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      } else if (stage_key === 'key3') {
        observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      } else if (stage_key === 'key4') {
        observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      } else if (stage_key === 'key5') {
        observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      } else if (stage_key === 'key6') {
        observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      } else {
        observer.next([NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]]);
      }

      // observable execution

      observer.complete();
    });

    return simpleObservable$;
  }
```

Comment: You can use switch case instead.

Comment: I don't understand why you need `if` at all. all you do is `observer.next([NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]])` in all the cases.

Comment: Am i missing something or you do the same thing inside every if?

Comment: @Pac0 but there are different stage keys

Comment: You just pass it on, so there is no point for an if statement

Comment: @OlegShchegolev still, the instruction is the same, it will replace in your string the proper value. Whether there is a if or not before.

Comment: the slight difference in the "else", is it a typo ? (the fact it returns an array `[ NOM....]` instead of `NOM....`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently functionaly equivalent to :

```
 const simpleObservable$ = new Observable<any>((observer) => {
   observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
   observer.complete();
 }
 return observer;
```

Without any `if` statement.

Also, this can be simplified further by static Observable creation methods :

```
return Rx.Observable.of(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
```

Comment: However, the last case in the OP code should emit an array.

Comment: I noticed and asked OP in a comment on question at the time, hasn't answered directly but accepted my answer, I guess it was a typo?

Comment: There are some deleted answers responding to the literal question, if you're looking for some possibilities @LookForAngular I'll copy some ideas here in comments. (upvote this comment if useful and I'll "transmit the upvote =)" to their author)

Comment: regular expression: `if(/^key[1-6]/.test(stage_key)) {
   observer.next(NOMINIEES[stage_key]);
}` (else same with array)

Comment: switch case: `switch(stage_key) { 
   case 'key1','key2','key3': { 
       observer.next(NOMINIEES[`${stage_key}`]);
      break; 
   } 
   default: { ` (same with array)

Comment: thats better. However i do guess too its a typo,unless the OP do handle both string and string[] outside of this observable